# How to get DOM from a file using jsdom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, jsdom

I'm using Node.js, its plugins Request and FS to save a Web page on my hard-disk. This is done by the following code :

```
function loadURL(url, file_path, handler) {
    request.get(url).on('error', (error) => handler(error)).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_path, {'flags' : 'w'}))
}
```

I would want, now, to get the HTML DOM from this local file thanks to the Node.JS plugin JSDOM.

Thus :

1. I must read this file thanks to the plugin FS ;
2. When all the file's HTML code is read, I must store the latter into a string ;
3. Finally, I must call : `jsdom.jsdom(the_string_containing_HTML_code)`.

Step 3 is simple to do. The second too maybe.
However... how could I read asynchronously the local file using FS ? `read` function should not be used according to the documentation ; instead I should use `pipe`... but the latter just attaches a `WritableStream` to a `ReadableStream`... it does not satisfy what I'm wanting.

NB : I really want to use asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case (AFAIK), [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) is perfectly acceptable. That method is asynchronous. The synchronous and ill-advised method is called fs.readFileSync().

I recommend using the invocation of [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that does not deal in streams, but simply returns a callback with the data:

```
function loadURL(url, file_path, handler) {
    request.get(url,(error,response,body) => {
        if (error) {
            handler(error,null);
        }
        fs.writeFile(file_path,body,'utf8',(err) => {
            if (err) {
                handler(err,null);
            }
            // now you can safely assume your file is written to disk
            // you still have $body in memory, but let's pretend you don't
            // for sake of this exersise
            fs.readFile(file_path,'utf8',(err,html) => {
                if (err) handler(err,null);
                jsdom.env(html,(err,window) => {
                    if (err) handler(err,null);
                    // SUCCESS!
                    handler(null,window);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This will work in low-cost workloads. If you want more nuanced control-flow, streams are good. But I'd recommend trying this way first.

This code assumes handler() has the signature `handler(err,window)`